# Changing options inside a function

Tags: options

I would like to make a function that can perform checks on its option values, and resets them to legal values if necessary. The option should still be accessible using OptionValue. I am looking for a way to do this without touching the function's default option values. A minimal example might look something like this:

```
ClearAll[f];
Options[f] = {"Opt1" -> 1};

f[opts:OptionsPattern[]] := 
  If[
   OptionValue["Opt1"] < 2, Print["Option value is fine."]; OptionValue["Opt1"],
   Print["Option value is illegal."]; resetOption["Opt1", -1]; OptionValue["Opt1"]
   ];

f["Opt1" -> 4]
```

This should return -1, but leave the default value at 1. Is there a good way to do this?

EDIT: My real-world function is using OptionValue in several places, and I am looking for a clean way to modify options without having to introduce additional variables. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found an acceptable solution using the OptionValue[f, opts, name] construct. Thanks!

```
ClearAll[f];

Options[f] = {"Opt1" -> 1};

f[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{options},

   options = List[opts];

   If[
    OptionValue[f, options, "Opt1"] < 2,
    Print["Option value is fine."]; OptionValue[f, options, "Opt1"],
    Print["Option value is illegal."]; 
    PrependTo[options, "Opt1" -> -1]; OptionValue[f, options, "Opt1"]
    ]
   ];

f[]
(* Option value is fine. *)
(* 1 *)

f["Opt1" -> 4]
(* Option value is illegal. *)
(* -1 *)
```

Comment: But in the main function you'll now need to replace all calls to `OptionValue["Opt1"]` with `OptionValue[f, options, "Opt1"]`

Comment: Sorry, my minimal example was possibly too minimal... ;) True, but in my case this solution makes recoding easy, because introduction of that options list makes everything else behave the same as before. For example I can pass options of f to another function g by using a construct like g[FilterRules[{options}, Options[f]}, Options[g]]. Before I have used g[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[f]}, Options[g]].

Answer (score 1):

This will work on your minimal example,

```
ClearAll[f];
Options[f] = {"Opt1" -> 1};

f[opts : OptionsPattern[]] := If[OptionValue["Opt1"] < 2,
   Print["Option value is fine."];
   OptionValue["Opt1"],
   Print["Option value is illegal."];
   OptionValue["Opt1"] /. {OptionValue["Opt1"] -> -1}
   ];

f["Opt1" -> 4]
Options[f]

"Option value is illegal."
(* -1 *)
(* {"Opt1" -> 1} *)
```

Sadly, it will not work if you are trying to do anything beyond this minimal example, as for some reason `ReplaceAll` won't go inside any other `Head`.  That is, if you replace `OptionValue["Opt1"] /. {OptionValue["Opt1"] -> -1}` with `(OptionValue["Opt1"] + 1)/. {OptionValue["Opt1"] -> -1}` then the result is `5` and not `0` as you would hope.

Comment: Yeah, the function that I am actually going to use is calling OptionValue in multiple instances. It is also passing its options to other functions using FilterRules. If possible I would like to change the option itself, and not the return value of OptionValue.

Comment: From what I can tell, you can change the option value using `SetOptions[f,"Opt1"->-1]` inside the function, but this does the exact opposite of what you want - it changes the default option but not the local one.  It seems that the local value of `OptionValue["Opt1"]` is passed to the function when it is called.

Comment: Why not use a workaround, putting something like this inside the function: `localopt1 = If[OptionValue["Opt1"] < 2, OptionValue["Opt1"], -1]` , and then using `localopt1` everywhere?

Comment: This would be the last resort... My real-world function is using OptionValue in several places, so I was more looking for a clean way to modify options without having to recode. I will specify the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If, for some reason, you really need to access modified option value using `OptionValue["Opt1"]`, then you could localize `OptionValue` symbol using `` Internal`InheritedBlock `` and assign something to local `OptionValue` like `OptionValue["Opt1"] = something`.

An environment that performs necessary localization:

```
ClearAll[withLocalOptionValue]
SetAttributes[withLocalOptionValue, HoldFirst]
withLocalOptionValue[body_] :=
    Internal`InheritedBlock[{OptionValue},
        Unprotect[OptionValue];
        body
    ]
```

Now you can wrap whole body of your function with `withLocalOptionValue` and inside it simply assign values to `OptionValue`:

```
ClearAll[f];
Options[f] = {"Opt1" -> 1};
f[OptionsPattern[]] :=
    withLocalOptionValue@If[OptionValue["Opt1"] < 2,
        Print["Option value is fine."];
        OptionValue["Opt1"]
    (* else *),
        Print["Option value is illegal."];
        OptionValue["Opt1"] = -1; 
        OptionValue["Opt1"]
   ]

f["Opt1" -> 4]
(* Option value is illegal. *)
(* -1 *)

f["Opt1" -> 0]
(* Option value is fine. *)
(* 0 *)
```

But this is a strange requirement, why not simply use `Module` or `With` and assign correct option value to local symbol, as suggested in [comment by  Jason B](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101174/changing-options-inside-a-function#comment274508_101177)?

```
ClearAll[f];
Options[f] = {"Opt1" -> 1};
f[OptionsPattern[]] :=
    Module[{opt1 = OptionValue["Opt1"]},
        If[opt1 < 2,
            Print["Option value is fine."]
        (* else *),
            Print["Option value is illegal."];
            opt1 = -1
        ];
        opt1
    ]

f["Opt1" -> 4]
(* Option value is illegal. *)
(* -1 *)

f["Opt1" -> 0]
(* Option value is fine. *)
(* 0 *)
```

or

```
ClearAll[f];
Options[f] = {"Opt1" -> 1};
f[OptionsPattern[]] :=
    With[{opt1 = Replace[OptionValue["Opt1"], val_ /; val >= 2 -> -1]},
        opt1
    ]

f["Opt1" -> 4]
(* -1 *)

f["Opt1" -> 0]
(* 0 *)
```

Comment: The solution using Internal`InheritedBlock is pretty cool! However, for now I'm sticking with the OptionValue[f, options, "Opt1"] solution, because it makes options passing easier. It's nice to have all options in one list and just prepend updated options, because one can pass options from f to g by using a construct like g[FilterRules[{options, Options[f]}, Options[g]].