# How to debug (by step-through) with OptionValues?

Tags: options, debugging

If I have a function illustrated by this simplified example...

```
f[a_, b_, c_, OptionsPattern[d -> 0]] := Module[{e},
  e = a + b;
  e += c;
  e += OptionValue[d];
  e]
```

... and I wish to debug it by breaking at the module and setting inputs, e.g.

```
f[a_, b_, c_, OptionsPattern[d -> 0]] := Module[{e},
```

> {a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3};

```
e = a + b;
e += c;
e += OptionValue[d];
e
```

Can something be set along with {a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3} so that `OptionValue[d]` will work?

In a realistic situation there may be several OptionValue variables throughout the program which would be cumbersome to change for debugging.

A possible solution is to write the code using the old approach. E.g.

```
f[a_, b_, c_, options___] := Module[{e, d2},
```

> {a, b, c} = {1, 2, 3}; options = Sequence[d -> 4];

```
opts = Join[{options}, {d -> 0}];
d2 = d /. opts;
e = a + b;
e += c;
e += d2;
e
```

***Screenshot***

[image]

Comment: I think that It is not possible to set values for `a`, `b`, `c` after you have interrupted execution because they are not variables. They are pattern names. Their values are substituted in immediately when a pattern match is found and a replacement happens.  If the were module variables like `e` then it would be possible to set other values for them.  `OptionValue` and `OptionsPattern` are special, I don't think it is even possible to implement them using the standard constructs we have available (please do correct me if I am wrong!). I have never looked at what `OptionValue` does in ...

Comment: ... a dialog that was entered when interrupting this function inside of the `Module`.

Comment: I tried to break inside of the module using an `Assert[False]` (as I usually do), and the stack window shows a "local" `OptionsPatternVariable` that looks just like a `Module` variable.  But setting it manually does not always have an effect. on the final output of the function.

Comment: Seeing your edit I do not understand the question. I can't think of a scenario where `a=1` would work in a dialog. How specifically are you setting it? If you just want to give the options pattern a name, you can always do so `f[opt : OptionsPattern[]]`.  No need to resort to the old version.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have added a screenshot to clarify.  I'm debugging by stepping through the code.  The function `f` is not defined in the process.  It's just a simple step-through to isolate problem code.

Comment: That makes a big difference.  `OptionValue` simply does not work outside of a function call.  It requires that context.  Also, you should be careful to pay attention to the differences between substitution and evaluation that may make function behave differently than its code takes out of context.

Comment: To be accurate, `OptionValue[d]` does not work without the context of a function call. `OptionValue[{d -> 1}, d]` will work fine.

Comment: Slightly related: [Changing options inside a function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101531/14303). If it's just for debugging, maybe you could `Unprotect@OptionValue` and simply assign to it: `OptionValue[d] = 0`?

Comment: @jkuczm For this kind of debugging Unprotect is fine.  I generally never use Unprotect so it didn't occur to me.  You should write it as an answer.

Comment: What is wrong with a tool like TracePrint/TraceScan instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually unprotecting and changing definitions of built-in symbols is a bad idea, but for code intended to be used only for debugging, it might be acceptable. So you could unprotect `OptionValue` and assign downvalues to it:

```
Unprotect@OptionValue;

{a, b, c, OptionValue[d]} = {1, 2, 3, 4};

e = a + b;
e += c;
e += OptionValue[d];
e
(* 10 *)
```

---

Alternatively if you want to make sure that all pattern variables and all calls to `OptionValue` behave like they do when evaluated inside function body, you could use special environment:

```
functionCallEnvironment = Function[patt, Function[call, Function[body,
    Replace[Unevaluated@call, Identity[RuleDelayed][Unevaluated@patt, body]],
HoldFirst], HoldFirst], HoldFirst];
```

Create environment generator for specific pattern of `f` function:

```
fEnvGenerator = functionCallEnvironment@f[a_, b_, c_, OptionsPattern[d -> 0]];
```

Create environment for specific values:

```
env = fEnvGenerator@f[1, 2, 3, d -> 4];
```

Evaluate some code in this specific environment:

```
env[
    e = a + b;
    e += c;
    e += OptionValue[d];
    e
]
(* 10 *)
```

To see that relevant values are inserted in right places we can evaluate held code:

```
env@Hold[
    e = a + b;
    e += c;
    e += OptionValue[d];
    e
]
(* Hold[e = 1 + 2; e += 3; e += OptionValue[d -> 0, {d -> 4}, d]; e] *)
```

Environment works for every possible way of calling `OptionValue`:

```
env = functionCallEnvironment[g@OptionsPattern@{d1 -> 1, d2 -> 2}]@g[d1 -> 3];

env@{
    OptionValue@d1,
    OptionValue@d2,
    OptionValue@{d1, d2},
    OptionValue[Automatic, Automatic, d1, Hold],
    OptionValue[{d1 -> 5, d2 -> 6}, d1 -> 7, {d1, d2}]
}
(* {3, 2, {3, 2}, Hold[3], {7, 6}} *)
```